I am seeing incorrect time format in streamlit app for data scrapping done through selenium and saved in Sql
I am not getting the correct departing and reaching time format in the Streamlit app.
I tried st.table(styler) but it was not helpful.
My database is in MySQL and connected to the Streamlit app using Python.
Here's the actual data:

Here's how it is coming in the Streamlit app:


you should paste your code too, not just screenshots

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
